# ggplot, count of the number of occurrences of a categorical variable and splitting this count according to a continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying hard to achieve something with ggplot but I keep failing !...

Here is a data.table

```
set.seed(12) 
data=data.table(categories=c('c','a','b','a','a','c','b','b','a','c','c','b'),hello=runif(12,0,15)
reclassification = c(0,4,7,15)
```

I'm trying to do the following plot:

y-axis : The 3 categories (a,b,c)

x-axis : A count of the number of times each category is found

colour/shape : The column "hello" reclassified according the vector "reclassification". There should have 3 colours in my example. One for the count of "categories" for 0 < hello < 4, one for 4 < hello < 7, one for 7 < hello < 15

Note: This plot can be made of bars, lines, volumes, several different plots, etc... (I would actually appreciate trying some different solutions)

Comment: If you are trying hard, please show some of your efforts.

Comment: Wow, did my question sound like a "please do my job" question !? Didn't expect this reaction. My tries were not done on a separate script so that I can hardly find all my tries as they are mixed with other work ! But anyway I can find some of them. It won't fit in a question or a comment, is there a way to attach a file ?

Comment: To make it briefly I tried with barplot, hist, ggplot, qplot, geom_histogram, geom_density, geom_bar, facet_wrap, .. many different parameters in these functions. I modified several times my data object also. If you think it is not worth answering to my question, I'll delete it and keep learning on http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/

Comment: You should decide what kind of plot you want before trying to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(12) 

DT <- data.table(categories=c('c','a','b','a','a','c','b','b','a','c','c','b'),hello=runif(12,0,15))
reclassification <- c(0,4,7,15)
DT[,colour:=cut(hello,c(-Inf,reclassification,Inf))]

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DT,aes(x=categories,fill=colour)) + geom_bar()
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Using position='dodge' in geom_bar this will be great. Thank you, Roland.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have some redundant information in this plot, because your x-axis gives the frequency of points in each category, yet you still need to plot all the points in order to display their reclassified values for `hello`. But then again, I'm not sure I fully understand how you want the colours applied.

You could do something along these lines:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(12)
# I've increased the number of categories here to provide a fuller example.
data <- data.table(categories=sample(letters[1:10], 50, replace=T), 
                   hello=runif(50, 0, 15)) 
reclassification = c(0, 4, 7, 15)

p <- ggplot(data, 
            aes(table(categories)[match(categories, names(table(categories)))], 
                categories, 
                col = cut(hello, reclassification)))

p + geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.15, height=0.15),
                shape=20, size=4) + 
  labs(list(x='Frequency', y='Category', col='Class')) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('#404040', '#CA0020', '#2B83BA'))
```

[image]

Comment: I started on this and then got side-tracked for a long while. Didn't realise @Roland had already provided a satisfactory solution.

Comment: Thank you jbaums for your answer !